# Batch Script to run on each user profile

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to run a batch script that will be used to copy a users Microsoft office customization that are saved in their APPDATA directory to their desktop and I am trying to find a way to have my script loop through C:\Users so that it will run on every user profile on a given computer and places these files on their desktop.

```
IF NOT EXIST "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Office365 Prep" mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Office365 Prep"
mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Office365 Prep\Signatures"
mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Office365 Prep\Dictonary"
mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Office365 Prep\Out Of office"
mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Office365 Prep\Ribbon Customizations"
mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Office365 Prep\Scripts_Config365"



robocopy "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Signatures" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Office365 Prep\Signatures" /e /np /mir /tee /log+:"\\serverName\log.txt"
robocopy "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\UProof" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Office365 Prep\Dictonary" /e /np /mir /log+:"\\serverName\log.txt"
robocopy "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Office365 Prep\Ribbon Customizations"  *.officeUI /log+:"\\serverName\log.txt"

robocopy "C:\kworking\O365" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Office365 Prep\Scripts_Config365"
```

Comment: In what way(s) does this code not meet your expectations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The environment variables `%USERPROFILE%` and `%APPDATA%` will reflect the currently logged-in user, so they likely won't work for what you're trying to do.  However, if all your machines are on a modern version of Windows (Vista, 7, 8.x, or 10) and your users have default folder locations (C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming) then you shouldn't have any trouble referencing them directly.

To loop through directories, use `for /d`.

```
for /d %%a in (C:\Users\*) do (
    IF NOT EXIST "%%a\Desktop\Office365 Prep" (
        mkdir "%%a\Desktop\Office365 Prep"
    )
    mkdir "%%a\Desktop\Office365 Prep\Signatures"
    mkdir "%%a\Desktop\Office365 Prep\Dictonary"
    mkdir "%%a\Desktop\Office365 Prep\Out Of office"
    mkdir "%%a\Desktop\Office365 Prep\Ribbon Customizations"
    mkdir "%%a\Desktop\Office365 Prep\Scripts_Config365"

    robocopy "%%a\AppData\Microsoft\Signatures" "%%a\Desktop\Office365 Prep\Signatures" /e /np /mir /tee /log+:"\\serverName\log.txt"
    robocopy "%%a\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UProof" "%%a\Desktop\Office365 Prep\Dictonary" /e /np /mir /log+:"\\serverName\log.txt"
    robocopy "%%a\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office" "%%a\Desktop\Office365 Prep\Ribbon Customizations"  *.officeUI /log+:"\\serverName\log.txt"

    robocopy "C:\kworking\O365" "%%a\Desktop\Office365 Prep\Scripts_Config365" 
)
```